# Nextcloud конфигурация NGinx

Tags: nginx, облако, httpbackend

Нужна помощь в настройки конфигурации frontend и backend серверов nginx.

На **frontend** HTTPS:

```
upstream http_cloud {
  server 192.168.1.211:80;  
  keepalive 32;
}

server {
  proxy_set_header Host $host;
  proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

  # Настройки облака

  location ~* /cloud {  
    proxy_pass http://http_cloud;
    proxy_redirect http://http_cloud $scheme://$host;
  }
}
```

На **backend** (192.168.1.211)  HTTP:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  charset utf-8;

  server_name localhost;

  access_log /var/log/nginx/nextcloud.access.log;
  error_log /var/log/nginx/nextcloud.error.log;

  add_header Strict-Transport-Security 'max-age=631138519; includeSubDomains; preload' always;
  add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;
  add_header X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN;
  add_header X-XSS-Protection '1; mode=block';
  add_header X-Robots-Tag none;
  add_header X-Download-Options noopen;
  add_header X-Permitted-Cross-Domain-Policies none;
  add_header X-Content-Security-Policy "allow 'self';";
  add_header X-WebKit-CSP "allow 'self';";

  root /usr/local/www/;

  location = /robots.txt {
    deny all;
  }

  location ^~ /cloud {

    client_max_body_size 10G;
    fastcgi_buffers 64 4K;

    gzip off;

    error_page 403 /cloud/core/templates/403.php;
    error_page 404 /cloud/core/templates/404.php;

    location = /cloud/data/htaccesstest.txt {
      allow all;
      log_not_found off;
      access_log off;
    }

    location ~ ^/cloud/(data|config|\.ht|db_structure\.xml|README) {
      deny all;
    }

    location ~* \/remote\/(?:.*)$ {
      rewrite ^ /remote.php last;
    }

    # поддержка загрузки превью
    location ~* \/core\/(?:js\/oc\.js|preview\.png).*$ {
      rewrite ^ /index.php last;
    }

    # поддержка загрузки файлов через веб-версию сайта
    location ~* \/apps\/(?:files\/ajax\/upload\.php).*$ {
      rewrite ^ /index.php last;
    }

    # поддежка кастомных тем Nextcloud
    location ~* \/apps\/(?:theming\/styles\.css).*$ {
      rewrite ^ /index.php last;
    }

    location /cloud {
      # редиректы для CalDAV, CardDAV, WebDAV
      rewrite ^/caldav(.*)$ /remote.php/caldav$1 redirect;
      rewrite ^/carddav(.*)$ /remote.php/carddav$1 redirect;
      rewrite ^/webdav(.*)$ /remote.php/webdav$1 redirect;

      rewrite ^(/core/doc/[^\/]+/)$ $1/index.html;

      # основной редирект для Pretty URL, с исключением статики
      if ($uri !~* (?:\.(?:css|js|svg|gif|png|html|ttf|woff)$|^\/(?:remote|public|cron|status|ocs\/v1|ocs\/v2)\.php)){
        rewrite ^ /index.php last;
      }
    }

    location ~* ^(?!\/remote\.php)(?:.*)\.(?:jpg|jpeg|gif|bmp|ico|png|css|js|swf|html|svg|ttf|woff)$ {
      # время жизни статических файлов, за исключением файлов, переданных через WebDAV
      expires 30d;
      access_log off;
    }

    location ~ \.php(?:$|/) {
      # PHP-обработчик
      fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm.sock;
      fastcgi_index index.php;
      include fastcgi_params;
      fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
      fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_script_name;

      # HTTPS
      fastcgi_param HTTPS off;

      # запрет дублирования заголовков
      fastcgi_param modHeadersAvailable true;

      # новый front controller для Pretty URL
      fastcgi_param front_controller_active true;

      # необязательные, но полезные параметры
      fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
      fastcgi_request_buffering off;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Должно помочь нечто подобное.
https://gist.github.com/Lord-Protector/3394a3f00bed31fe054f1d911c51edca

Сразу работать вряд ли будет. Нужно отлаживать.
Сравните вот эти два примера: https://docs.nextcloud.com/server/9/admin_manual/installation/nginx_nextcloud_9x.html

Они помогут понять в чем разница между.

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь публиковать развернутые ответы содержащие конкретный пример минимального решения, дополняя их ссылкой на источник. Ответы–ссылки (как и комментарии) не добавляют знаний в Рунет.

Answer (score 0):

на **backend**:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  charset utf-8;

  server_name localhost;

  access_log /var/log/nginx/nextcloud.access.log;
  error_log /var/log/nginx/nextcloud.error.log;

  root /usr/local/www/;

  location = /robots.txt {
    deny all;
  }

  location / {
    deny all;
    return 404;
  }

  location ^~ /cloud {

    client_max_body_size 10G;
    fastcgi_buffers 64 4K;

    gzip off;

    error_page 403 /cloud/core/templates/403.php;
    error_page 404 /cloud/core/templates/404.php;

    location /cloud {
      # rewrite ^ /cloud/index.php$uri;

      # редиректы для CalDAV, CardDAV, WebDAV
      rewrite ^/cloud/caldav(.*)$ /cloud/remote.php/caldav$1 redirect;
      rewrite ^/cloud/carddav(.*)$ /cloud/remote.php/carddav$1 redirect;
      rewrite ^/cloud/webdav(.*)$ /cloud/remote.php/webdav$1 redirect;

      rewrite ^(/cloud/core/doc/[^\/]+/)$ $1/index.html;

      # основной редирект для Pretty URL, с исключением статики
      if ($uri !~* (?:\.(?:css|js|svg|gif|png|html|ttf|woff)$|^\/cloud\/(?:remote|public|cron|status|ocs\/v1|ocs\/v2)\.php)){
        rewrite ^ /cloud/index.php last;
      }
    }

    location = /cloud/data/htaccesstest.txt {
      allow all;
      log_not_found off;
      access_log off;
    }

    location ~ ^/cloud/(data|config|\.ht|db_structure\.xml|README) {
      deny all;
    }

    location ~* \/cloud\/remote\/(?:.*)$ {
      rewrite ^ /cloud/remote.php last;
    }

    # поддержка загрузки превью
    location ~* \/cloud\/core\/(?:js\/oc\.js|preview\.png).*$ {
      rewrite ^ /cloud/index.php last;
    }

    # поддержка загрузки файлов через веб-версию сайта
    location ~* \/cloud\/apps\/(?:files\/ajax\/upload\.php).*$ {
      rewrite ^ /cloud/index.php last;
    }

    # поддежка кастомных тем Nextcloud
    location ~* \/cloud\/apps\/(?:theming\/styles\.css).*$ {
      rewrite ^ /cloud/index.php last;
    }

    location ~* ^(?!\/cloud\/remote\.php)(?:.*)\.(?:jpg|jpeg|gif|bmp|ico|png|css|js|swf|html|svg|ttf|woff)$ {
      # время жизни статических файлов, за исключением файлов, переданных через WebDAV
      expires 30d;
      access_log off;
    }

    location ~ \.php(?:$|/) {
      # PHP-обработчик
      include fastcgi_params;
      fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
      fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
      fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm.sock;

      # HTTPS
      fastcgi_param HTTPS off;

      # запрет дублирования заголовков
      fastcgi_param modHeadersAvailable true;

      # новый front controller для Pretty URL
      fastcgi_param front_controller_active true;

      # необязательные, но полезные параметры
      fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
      fastcgi_request_buffering off;
    }

  }
}
```